# How to get json or array result out of callback function in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a function in NodeJs

```
function ga_data(view, callback) { 

    overview = {orgaincCount:12,sessionsCount:3,newUserCount:4,sessionArray:session};

    callback(1, overview);
}
```

Calling a fucntion

```
ga_data(view, function(err, result)  {
if (err == 0) {
  jsonString = {err : 1, result : []}
} else {
    // res.send({status: 1, message: "Success",overview: result});
    jsonString = {err : 0, result : result}
}

});
```

Now I want to access the callback result outside the callback function i.e.

```
ga_data(view, function(err, result) {
if (err == 0) {
   jsonString = {err : 1, result : result};
} else {
    jsonString = {err : 0, result : result};
}
});
console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: you can't - because asynchronous code is asynchronous and nothing will change that

Comment: You need another callback.

Comment: To access the callback result outside the callback function you can emit update event, and handle that 'update' event.

Create jsonString as an event emitter and subscribing to events.

    var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
    var jsonString = new EventEmitter();
    
            jsonString.emit('update');
    
    jsonString.on('update', function () {
        console.log(jsonString.result); //  THIS WORKS!
    });